# PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX produce different font shape

Tags: fonts, xetex, pdftex

Why the compilation of the code

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}

\sffamily {\huge\bfseries Some text in sffamily}

\end{document}
```

with PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX produces distinct font shape? Thanks.

Comment: pdflatex will use the ec fonts, xelatex the latin modern fonts. But you shouldn't use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with xelatex.

Comment: Yes, but my intention is to obtain the PDFLaTeX output (i.e. the pdf produced after the PDFLaTeX compilation with ```\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}```) using XeLaTeX compilation. This is possible?

Comment: No. you can't get the identical output, and you will run into problems with hyphenation and non-ascii chars.

Comment: you can (with some difficulty) use T1 encoding with lualatex but not with xelatex as it does not load any hyphenation patters for 8 bit encodings. so never use `fonttenc` with xelatex.